# DynamicRecord - what is it?

Tags: dynamic, neo4j, record

When I run the following query:

```
match (n) return distinct labels(n);
```

I am seeing the following error:

```
DynamicRecord[396379,used=false,(0),type=-1,data=byte[],start=true,next=-1] not in use
```

Other people have asked how to deal with this situation.  I am asking a different set of questions: what is a DynamicRecord in Neo4j?  And, what can be done to avoid this type of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What is DynamicRecord

The source for DynamicRecord is [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.4.6/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/store/record/DynamicRecord.java). This is largely useless.

Anyhow, all I can gather is that it is:

- It is a very low-level construct in store kernal.
- A [multitude of tests](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/search?q=DynamicRecord&unscoped_q=DynamicRecord) use it with relation to consistency checking.
- It appears to be a record that is dynamically created (meaning, at run time - not stored on disk), and it can represent different type of data (property blocks, schema, etc.)

This is also largely useless. I know.

## What can be done to avoid this type of error.

This seems to be a very generic error, but most online resources (Github issues / SO questions) seem to relate to DB upgrades. Some pointed out in changes to some consts used by DynamicRecord that yield data-corruption after upgrades.

Based on that, I guess that the following steps could prevent such error:

- Backup your data.
- Migrate your data properly when upgrading.
- Do not use different versions of neo against the same data.

You've guessed it - This is also rather useless, but I hope it is better than nothing.